# How to seed data for role base authentication using Microsoft Identity Framework in asp.net 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, c3.js, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created two static class
DefaultRoles.cs

```
using DCMS.Web.Constants;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace DCMS.Web.Seeds

{
public class DefaultRoles
{
    public static async Task SeedAsync(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Admin.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Manager.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.SalesStaff.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Basic.ToString()));
    }
}
```

and my DefaultUser.cs Class Like-

```
using DCMS.Web.Constants;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace DCMS.Web.Seeds
{
    public static class DefaultUsers
    {
        public static async Task SeedBasicUserAsync(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            // Seed Basic User
            var defaultUser = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = "dcmsbasicuser@gmail.com",
                Email = "dcmsbasicuser@gmail.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true
            };
            if (userManager.Users.All(u => u.Id != defaultUser.Id))
            {
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(defaultUser.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    await userManager.CreateAsync(defaultUser, "100%Pa$$word");
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultUser, Roles.Basic.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task SeedSuperAdminUserAsync(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            // Seed SuperAdmin User
            var defaultUser = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = "dcmssuperadminuser@gmail.com",
                Email = "dcmssuperadminuser@gmail.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true
            };
            if (userManager.Users.All(u => u.Id != defaultUser.Id))
            {
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(defaultUser.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    await userManager.CreateAsync(defaultUser, "100%SuperAdminPa$$word");
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultUser, Roles.Basic.ToString());
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultUser, Roles.Admin.ToString());
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultUser, Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString());
                }
                await roleManager.SeedClaimsForSuperAdmin();
            }
        }

        private static async Task SeedClaimsForSuperAdmin(this RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            var adminRole = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString());
            await roleManager.AddPermissionClaim(adminRole, "Products");
        }
        public static async Task AddPermissionClaim(this RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IdentityRole role, string module)
        {
            var allClaims = await roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            var allPermissions = Permissions.GeneratePermissionsForModule(module);
            foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
            {
                if(!allClaims.Any(a => a.Type=="Permission" && a.Value == permission))
                {
                    await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim("Permission", permission));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to Inject those class into program.cs class. my program.cs class like-

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DCMS.Web.Data;
using DCMS.Web.Seeds;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder => {
    containerBuilder
.RegisterModule(new WebModule());
});

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration));

try
{
    var app = builder.Build();
    Log.Information("Application Starting up");

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    app.MapRazorPages();

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

How can I do? Basically I want to seed data from those class for user authentication. I am using asp.net 6.0. please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Did this case work for you? https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/58939935/how-to-seed-asp-net-core-identity-users-as-part-of-ef-migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code to program.cs file

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            await DefaultRoles.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
            await DefaultUsers.SeedBasicUserAsync(userManager, roleManager);
            await DefaultUsers.SeedSuperAdminUserAsync(userManager, roleManager);
            Log.Information("Identity User Data Seeding finished");
        } 
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Now program.cs file will be like this-

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DCMS.Web.Data;
using DCMS.Web.Seeds;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder => {
    containerBuilder
.RegisterModule(new WebModule());
});

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration));

try
{
    var app = builder.Build();
    Log.Information("Application Starting up");


    // Need to add for data seeding Start
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            await DefaultRoles.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
            await DefaultUsers.SeedBasicUserAsync(userManager, roleManager);
            await DefaultUsers.SeedSuperAdminUserAsync(userManager, roleManager);
            Log.Information("Identity User Data Seeding finished");
        } 
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    // Need to add for data seeding End

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    app.MapRazorPages();

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```